# how to get the video fully viewed (API Youtube PHP)

Tags: php, html, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i'm trying get the information of a video, only viewed until the end.

If i add this in my application:

```
echo '<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"/>'
```

Is there any way to know when the user finishes watching the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you'll have to use the [javascript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for this:

```
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      // video ended -- do something here...
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have another question, how i can do a insert in my database into this function, that is:

Comment: I have another question, how i can do a insert in my database into this function?, that is: function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      // do insert in databases here
    }
  }

Comment: Remember this javascript code runs in the browser (client-side) even though you output it with PHP on the server side... So you'll likely need to do an ajax call back to your server for this, either to an endpoint that returns some data, (json or error) or to an image beacon if you don't really care about the server's response.